# Помогите выбрать из таблицы уникальные значения с сортировкой по дате laravel 5

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Доброго времени суток!

Из таблицы необходимо получить список полей: `name`, `number` и `date`, сортирую по дате, чтобы записи с самой новой датой шли по убыванию сверху/вниз. Но при этом, надо исключать повтор записей с одинаковыми полями `name` и `number`, а подобных будет много.

Помогите допилить запрос:

```
$info = $this->db->table('table')->select('name', 'number', 'date')->where('hash', $hash)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->distinct()->get()->toArray();
```

Этот запрос исключает повторы одинаковых `name` и `number`, но и некорректно выполняет сортировку по полю `created_at` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую попробовать сгрупировать значения по name затем по number ,тем самым исключив повторы.

```
$info = $this->db->table('table')->select('name', 'number', 'date')
->where('hash', $hash)->groupBy('name', 'number')
->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Что мой, что Ваш запрос корректно сортирует по дате записи только разных пользователей. У меня для проверки в базе есть повторяющиеся пользователи с одинаковыми именами и номерами, но разными датами создания(created_at), так они в самом низу списка, даже если их записи в таблице последние! Сортировка не отрабатывает.

Comment: Хотя вроде норм. Спасибо

Comment: Важна последовательность. Если проблема решена - ставьте галочку на против правильного ответа, таким образом вопрос на данном ресурсе счиатаеться закрытым.